# Programmatically insert a circle with pattern using Interop in C#

Tags: c#, office-interop

I want to insert a circle with hatching in a word document. How to achieve this using Interop?
The desired output looks as follows:

[image]

The following code produces circle filled with color and not lines:

```
public void CirclewithPattern(Document doc)
{
    int shapeType = (int)MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeOval;
    Shape shape = doc.Shapes.AddShape(shapeType, 40, 100, 10, 10);
    
    shape.Fill.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
    shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (int)0xFFFFFF;
    shape.Fill.Transparency = 0.5f;

    // Set the angle of the diagonal stripes
    shape.Rotation = 45; 

    // Create a pattern of diagonal stripes with separation 
    shape.Line.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
    shape.Line.ForeColor.RGB = (int)0x000000;
    shape.Line.Weight = 2;
    shape.Line.DashStyle = MsoLineDashStyle.msoLineSysDot;
}
```

Comment: You are supposed to provide an example of what you have tried, not just a mission statement. 
Stackoverflow states in it's guidelines that this borders on asking for a code writing service, and that is not stackoverflows intention. It's a help forum. You have to provide an actual attempt on the task, and a specific error that you can't overcome.

Comment: I would suggest you add the shape in excel, do format shape, choose pattern fill to pick the pattern which meets your need, change its background/foreground color and record a macro of it.